# Design patterns for handling UILocalNotifications (how to know where user is within branching app)

Tags: ios, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I have an app which uses UILocalNotifications (though the question would also be relevant to PushNotifications). When the user receives a local notification, depending on the state of the app and the choice they make in the notification alert, I want to present a specific viewController. The issue is they may currently be in a "pushed" viewController through a segue or in a modal ViewController and I am not currently tracking where the user is within the possible branches.

I am wondering if there is any sort of design pattern or standard way of handling a mixed presentation mode app like this? Particularly if there is any built-in way to determine which is/are the active ViewController(s) without my having to setup a breadcrumb system. This would matter, for example, if the user is already viewing the viewController to be called as a result of the localNotification.

I realize my need/explanation is a little muddled. I'll edit and update this if anyone needs more info.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I think I have a solution through the Apple docs [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS: Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1)

> Each view controller in a chain of presented view controllers has
>   pointers to the other objects surrounding it in the chain. In other
>   words, a presented view controller that presents another view
>   controller has valid objects in both its presentingViewController and
>   presentingViewController properties. You can use these relationships
>   to trace through the chain of view controllers as needed. For example,
>   if the user cancels the current operation, you can remove all objects
>   in the chain by dismissing the first presented view controller. In
>   other words, dismissing a view controller dismisses not only that view
>   controller but also any view controllers it presented.

So I can cancel any chain of modal viewControllers by dismissing the first modal viewController in the chain.

I can determine if there is currently a modal viewController being presented using:

```
 self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController
```

If the property is null then there no modal viewController is currently being presented. And for completeness (hackishness..) I can test is the presentedViewController has a presentedViewController, etc.:

```
self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController.presentedViewController
```